# Place methods of a subobject in my class

Tags: python, class, methods

I know that what I'm doing is probably not the best way to do it, but right now I can't think of another way.

What I basically have is this:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = ['bundy']
```

Currently, I'm defining a lot of methods for my class to return the result of the method on the list, like this:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.bar)
```

Of course, there are also other methods and objects which are not to do with `bar` - I'm not reinventing the `list`

Is there an easier way to 'copy' the methods, so that I don't have to define them all one by one?

Comment: Which list methods do you want to copy? All of them?

Comment: Currently, yes, all of them - I think all my other methods are going to be ... not `__` 'd (What's the word for that?)

Comment: Can you just inherit from `list`?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no - as all of `list`'s methods would work on `list`'s list attribute (?) rather than `bar`

Comment: Why does `bar` have to be an attribute? If you want to implement all of the same methods as `list`, and then add some of your own, that sounds an awful lot like extending the `list` class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define some methods one by one, like you are doing.
However, there is a base-class in Python, other than list, that gives you a well defined way of which methods you need to supply, and defines the remaining methods that can be based on this minimum set.

These are the provided "[abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html)" - what you want is to implement your object as a "Mutable Sequence" - them you only have to implement `__getitem__, __setitem__, __delitem__, __len__, insert` to have the full list functionality.

In python 3.x, just inherit your class from `collections.abc.MutableSequence` and implement those. (In Python 2.7 it is `collection.MutableSequence` instead.).

By doing this, you will get for free `__contains__, __iter__, __reversed__, index, count, append, reverse, extend, pop, remove` and `__iadd__`   methods.